# Why won't this css work as expected in MVC project?

Tags: html, css, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to draw a yin-yang symbol with css in my MVC project. So I found some css, which does what I want:

```css
#yin-yang {
  width: 96px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #eee;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px 2px 50px 2px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#yin-yang:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border: 18px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
#yin-yang:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: red;
  border: 18px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="yin-yang"></div>
```

I can easily get it to work in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15ee603g/):

[image: Yin-Yang looking good]

But as soon as I insert it [in my MVC project](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A4ZyAy), it draws all wrong

[image: Yin-Yang not good]

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Have you got other CSS on your page that may be overwriting your styles?

Comment: Remove `box-sizing` and `webkit-box-sizing` properties

Comment: Commenting out the <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> makes it work in dotnetfiddle too, so as @StephenMuecke suggested, must be something in there.

Comment: Stephen Muecke: Can you describe how to do this a little more in depth?

Comment: See [forked DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IYGQVn) (just add `box-sizing: initial;` to each style to override the bootstrap defaults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using bootstrap css which is including `box-sizing: border-box;` which is causing the distortion. You an override this by adding

```
box-sizing: initial;
```

to each of your `#yin-yang` styles (including the `:before` and `:after`)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using *Bootstrap* Framework in your MVC or in DotnetFiddle and it has some *Reset CSS* as well as some basic properties like `box-sizing` which clearly neglects all the affected height OR width of any elements which varied due to `padding` and `border` etc(in your case your pseudo elements).

Using this **CSS** or can say altering your **CSS** you can get that to work in your environment too as:

```
#yin-yang {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    background: #eee;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 2px 50px 2px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#yin-yang:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background: #eee;
    border: 18px solid red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
}
#yin-yang:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    background: red;
    border: 18px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
}
```